# Facebook PHP SDK - User not authenticated

Tags: php, facebook, cookies

I am using Facebook PHP SDK to authenticate the user. After generating the `LoginUrl` using the PHP SDK, the user clicking on that `LoginUrl` gets redirected to the Facebook page asking for permission. After clicking on the `Go to App` link, the user gets redirected back to my website `http://www.mydomain.com/login/facebook_connect`.

**Problem:** After being 'authenticated' by Facebook, the PHP script at `http://www.mydomain.com/login/facebook_connect` is unable to determine that the user has logged in via Facebook. At this point, `$user = $facebook->getUser();` is 0.

Did I do something wrong? Thanks!

**PHP Code for page that generates `LoginUrl`**

```
require 'libs/fb-php-sdk/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '123',
  'secret' => '123'
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// Get Login URL
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    "scope" => "email,user_education_history,user_work_history",
    "redirect_uri" => "http://www.mydomain.com/login/facebook_connect/"
));

$data['fb_login_url'] = $loginUrl;

$this->load->view('splash', $data);
```

**PHP Code for page user is redirected to after Facebook authentication**

*http://www.mydomain.com/login/facebook_connect/*

```
require 'libs/fb-php-sdk/facebook.php';

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => '123',
        'secret' => '123',
    ));

    // See if there is a user from a cookie
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    // We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
    //
    // If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
    // Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
    // token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

    if ($user) {
      try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
      }
    }

    print_r($user_profile);
    echo $user;
```

Comment: When facebook redirects back to your site, did you check the full url? There should be an access_token param.

Comment: The redirection is working fine now, using `redirect_uri` instead of `next`.

Comment: This is the url I get after redirection back to my site from Facebook authentication page: `http://www.mydomain.com/facebook_pickup.php?state=f210c06a9854f43edd12bdb57993e1da&code=AQCUp3YsSVNa2LfnKR1EXr_wq3BapIHJ5qr7nNury0fJQidb-nnkn2ZIxImMvN92CtiLwkZTmmzWelv9Lt8EDor2Q2YmKSDI6OoFTiNe8OZdDLLO5YATYA4-Bc1_y8qOcwOzq8-gzj4u__BwuLJLJFYe4e4plXgREYK6EbTXB872QCtz2aiSen0dpHPSdkfXncs#_=_` There is no access_token param...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$facebook->getUser() uses a cookie to get the user. If you use CodeIgniter, or another library that "eats" cookies that PHP assigns automatically, you need to create a proxy page outside CI, that would pick up the cookie the redirect back into CI.

In other words, take to code you currently have in

```
http://www.mydomain.com/login/facebook_connect/
```

and create a copy in a regular PHP file:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/facebook_pickup.php
```

do not echo anything from the script (remove print_r), just redirect to

```
http://www.mydomain.com/login/facebook_connect/
```

and it would magically start working.

Comment: Is there anyway to prevent Codeigniter from automatically eating the cookie just for that controller function?

Comment: Can I include just in `http://www.mydomain.com/facebook_pickup.php` `$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => '123',
        'secret' => '123',
    ));

    // See if there is a user from a cookie
    $user = $facebook->getUser();`
and still access $facebook and $user from `http://www.mydomain.com/login/facebook_connect/`after teh 2nd redirection?

Answer (score 2):

All seems correct.

Questions:
1.- I supposed that http://www.mydomain.com/ contains all your scripts, right?
2.- Are you using codeigniter? Or a codeigniter-based CMS? In that case maybe you have a session problem (very common in CI). Check it and we continue...

---

EDIT 2: In case of being a cookie related problem. Here is an image showing as you can use firebug with a cookie module to easily track your cookies:

[image]

So you can check how facebook cookies are being generated.

---

EDIT 3: Ok. So you are using CI and your FB cookies are being deleted. Maybe is a session problem. Here is a [related answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/991Xh.png) where I explain how to use a session CI library replacement that generally solve all these kind of painful issues. Believe me, give it a try!

a.- Here it is: [Codeigniter's Native session](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Native_session) (there is a download link at the bottom)

b.- BUT, due that it is an old library you MUST made some hacks. You can check those simple hacks in the [library's forum](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/103583/P30/#910927)

c.- Just drop this file in codeigniter's library directory.

Comment: :) I knew it! The answer gives by Milan Babuškov seems quite ingenious. If not works I can recommend you a session based solution. I'll be here...

Comment: I'm puzzled why Codeigniter deletes the facebook cookies? And was the cookie set by Facebook created right after Facebook authenticates the user for my websiste? Or did the PHP SDK set the cookie?

Comment: As the previous image show the cookies are planted by FB. So I really think that it is a CI issue. Try the session solution (EDIT 3) and see. Good Luck colleague!